# when do I get the sum 5? 1/i + 1/i+1

Tags: for-loop

At what 'i' do I get sum = 5 ?
My code :
-ps im a beginner.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; sum < 5; i++) {
sum =  sum + 1/i;
}
```

Comment: try declaring i before for loop and print the value after the for loop to know the same.

Comment: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: integer division: `1/2 = 0,1/3=0, 1/4=0, ...` - never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trickier question than you might expect, for two reasons:

1. For all iterations where i > 1, you will not be changing sum at all. This is due to the fact that i and 1 are both integers. This means that 1/i is calculated using integer division. Integer division will always round a number down to the nearest integer. 1/i will result in 0 for all i > 1.
2. At this point you might expect that the program would simply run forever, and the answer would be "sum will never become 5", however, there is a second effect at play here, integer overflow. Simple integers, such as the int datatype, have a maximum value. If you increment an int beyond its maximum value, you will end up with its minimum value. This is due to 2's complement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This means that i will become negative, and 1/i will result in some negative number aaaand this question suddenly becomes a lot trickier.

Short answer: I have no idea, but the question is tricky.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used doubles and it finally worked! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`sum` needs to be declares as `double` because `integer` will treat truncate all decimals.

`1/i` need to be type-casted as `double` as `i` is `integer` so `1/i` will be treated as `integer` so it'll give 1 for `i=1` and 0 for all `i>1` values.

```
double sum = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = 1; sum < 5; i++) {
     sum =  sum + (double) 1/i;
}
System.out.println("Sum = 5 for i = "+i);
```